# Create new binary column conditional on other column in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Trying to input a scoring system into R so I can validate it for my data.

I want to assign a score to set binary outcomes.

In this case if my patient has haemaglobin (Hb) <8 (yes 1 or no 0). I want to assign a score of 5 points when haemoglobin (Hb<8) = 1.

```
| Patient number | Hb<8 |
|----------------|------|
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
```

How do I create a new column that would read either 0 or 5 depending on the factor in the Hb column?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(patient = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 hb_smaller_8 = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

df <- df %>% mutate(score = ifelse(hb_smaller_8 == 1, 5, 0))
```

```
> df
  patient hb_smaller_8 score
1       1            0    NA
2       2            1     5
3       3            0    NA
4       4            1     5
```

Comment: @docalexh: Thanks. Consider accepting the answer if it works for you. This indicates to everyone that the question is answered. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ifelse`statement in `base R` will do:

```
df$score <- ifelse(df$hb_smaller_8 == 1, 5, NA)

df
  patient hb_smaller_8 score
1       1            0    NA
2       2            1     5
3       3            0    NA
4       4            1     5
```